# AWS private API Gateway through VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

First of all I am very new to AWS.
Here is what i'm trying to achieve:

- 1 VPC

  - 2 Subnet

    - 1 public that contain some EC2 instance
    - 1 private that contain an API Gateway only accessible by the EC2 instance

The public subnet is working perfectly well, I can access SSH and HTTP.
The private subnet cause me a little trouble. For debug purpose i launched off an EC2 instance in it. From one of the "public instance" I am able to ping the "private instance" private IP (Well there is no public IP obviously)

Following the documentation, I created a VPC Endpoint in my private subnet which created a Network interface where i attached a security group that allow HTTP(S) (80 and 443) from the whole VPC CIDR. The endpoint type is Interface

So, now i have a private subnet with an Endpoint that allow HTTP(S) traffic. That endpoint have some (private) DNS NAME and (probably) also a private IP (Could not find it)

Now I want to add an API Gateway to front some AWS lambda. 
I create said API and as an Endpoint Type -> Private

Following this : [Official Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html)
The "only" way to "link" the API Gateway to the VPC Endpoint is to add a resource policy. So I input the following

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<MY ID>:<API GATEWAY ID>/*/*/<MY RESOURCE>",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpce": "<VPC ENDPOINT ID>"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<MY ID>:<API GATEWAY ID>/*/*/<MY RESOURCE>"
    }
]
```

}

And for the sake of completeness here is my lambda (python3.6):

```
from __future__ import division
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  return {
      "statusCode":200,
      "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json" },
      "body" : "It work!"
  }
```

Finally the problem:

What would be the URL to invoke this REST Api!
API Gateway (In the lamdba Console) Tell me this:

```
https://<API GATEWAY ID>.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<MY STAGE>/<MY RESOURCE>
```

Ok! Lets call that url: APIURL
I ssh to the EC2 instance in the public subnet and run the following:

```
curl https://$APIURL
```

And it work: It output: "It work!" but that APIURL does not seem to come from the VPC endpoint so I try the following (still from the public subnet EC2):

```
curl https://vpce-XXXXXXX-XXXX.execute-api.REGION.vpce.amazonaws.com/<MY STAGE>/<MY RESOURCE>
```

And i get: {"message":"Forbidden"}

That does not seem right. As i test i change de API Gateway resource policy for the following:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<MY ID>:<API ID>/*/*/<MY RESOURCE>"
    }
]
```

}

And NOTHING changed. The APIURL is still working and the VPCE Url still give me forbidden.

What am I doing wrong? My apologies for the long post.

Comment: if you update the resource policy, you need to deploy your api again. Otherwise, the changes will have no effect.

Comment: None of the answer provided despite giving useful information for people running in a similar issue really answer it. I think the problem was to "redeploy" it so it take the new configuration. Could you provide an answer base on your comment so i can accept it?

Comment: absolutely -- added an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A policy role update does not take effect until the api has been deployed to a stage.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html

> If you update the resource policy after the API is created, you'll need to deploy the API to propagate the changes after you've attached the updated policy.

Answer (score 0):

As your API url is working fine,there seems to be a problem with the policy. 

In IAM policy **Deny** permission will override the **Allow** permission.  Try changing your policy to the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/*",
            "Condition": {
              "StringEquals":{
                             "aws:SourceVpce": "<VPC Endpoint ID>"
                         }
                       }
                    ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/*"
            ],
            "Condition" : {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "<VPC Endpoint ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For further reference, follow this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

Comment: Actually this is not an IAM Policy but Resource Policy in the API Gateway. (APIs -> MyApi -> Resource Policy). And When i change it to deny everything it still work. Should I be able to use the VPCE DNS to access the resource?

Comment: As far as I know, I could enter a Pie recipes in the Resource Policy (as long as it is valid json) and it would behave the same way. It seem to be completely ignore what I input. I am definitely missing something